# Why is a file with 400 permissions seen writable by root but read-only by user?

Tags: permissions, test, readonly

If I create a file as an unprivileged user, and change the permissions mode to `400`, it's seen by that user as read-only, correctly:

```
$ touch somefile
$ chmod 400 somefile
$ [ -w somefile ] && echo rw || echo ro
ro
```

All is well.

But then root comes along:

```
# [ -w somefile ] && echo rw || echo ro
rw
```

What the heck? Sure, root can write to read-only files, but it shouldn't make a habit of it: Best Practice would tend to dictate that I should be able to test for the write permission bit, and if it's not, then it was set that way for a reason.

I guess I want to understand both *why* this is happening, and *how* can I get a **false** return code when testing a file that doesn't have the write bit set?

Comment: btw I'm using both RHEL6 (`4.1.2(1)-release`) and RHEL7 (`4.2.46(2)-release`).

Comment: "Best Practice would tend to dictate that I should be able to test for the write permission bit, and if it's not, then it was set that way for a reason." - Actually, best practice is "don't run stuff as root."  If you're running as root, you've already decided to bypass permission checks.  Manually re-implementing those permission checks in userspace is a recipe for [disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem).

Comment: @Kevin Good for you if you can run stuff unprivileged. This is for manipulating `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`, which is owned by root. I'm using the vendor-supplied `dhcpd`. Total disaster, huh? The file is checked into RCS, I'm automating use of `rcsdiff`, `ci` and `co` because we have _operators_ that need to ... operate. The permission bit check (`-w`, as detailed by `test(1)`) was going to be a first line of failure, working on the basis that `ci -u` leaves a file read-only. I'm ditching that and going straight to `rcsdiff -q` and checking `$?`. Undisastrous `dhcpd`? It would be owned by `dhcpd`.

Comment: It's a *potential* disaster because you now have two different implementations of permissions checks: one in the kernel and one in userspace.  Worse, those implementations are not even intended to produce identical results, so you can't just fuzz test them against each other.  So now you have two paths to access which have to be locked down and secured independently of each other.

Comment: @Kevin Sure, they don't produce identical results and weren't intended to (despite the paucity of detail in manpages), but I explicitly want to _check the write-permission bit_; and the manpages for `bash` and `test` led me to believe that's what `[ -w` is for.

Comment: If you want to prevent even root from accidentally modifying a file, try `chattr +i`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48578108/321973

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`test -w` aka `[ -w` doesn't check the file mode. It checks if it's writable. For root, it is.

```
$ help test | grep '\-w'
  -w FILE        True if the file is writable by you.
```

The way I would test would be to do a bitwise comparison against the output of `stat(1)` ("`%a`   Access rights in octal").

```
(( 0$(stat -c %a somefile) & 0200 )) && echo rw || echo ro
```

Note the subshell `$(...)` needs a `0` prefixed so that the output of `stat` is interpreted as octal by `(( ... ))`.

Comment: Thanks for being concise. Good use of `(( ... & ... ))`. One typo corrected :-)

Comment: Make that 3... No `if` required, octal permissions output is `%a` not `%d`, and `(( ... ))` needs a prefixed `0` to interpret the output of `stat` as octal.

Comment: @Patrick my `man stat` says "%d device number in decimal", but what we want are the "access rights", no? Your point about needing the 0 prefix is well-made, but I guess we just have to bodge it in there :).

Comment: `stat -c 0%a` ...

Comment: @sourcejedi ack, you're right. For some reason I was thinking %d was access rights in decimal. Restored the edit. thanks :-)

Answer (score 32):

I think you have have misunderstood what `-w` does.  It does not check to see if the file has "Write permissions", it checks to see if the file is writable by the *invoking* user.

More specifically, it calls `access(2)` or similar.

eg if a script has `if [ -w /etc/shadow ]` then if you run `strace` on the script you may see a line similar to

```
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/shadow", W_OK)
```

Since `root` can write to the file then it returns 0.

eg as a normal user:

```
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/shadow", W_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

As root

```
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/shadow", W_OK) = 0
```

This, despite the fact that `/etc/shadow` has permission `000` on my machine.

```
---------- 1 root root 4599 Jan 29 20:08 /etc/shadow
```

Now what you want to do gets *interesting* and isn't so simple.

If you want to check the simple permissions then check the `ls` output, or call `stat` or similar.  But realize that ACLs can over-ride these permissions.  Just because a file is permission 400 doesn't stop it from being writable...

Comment: No, "misunderstanding" would be reading the manpages wrong for `-w`: `test(1)` is explicit: "FILE exists and _write permission_ is granted", not "_file may be written by current user_". Nothing about _overriding_ permissions, nor ACLs. `bash(1)` is cagey: "True if file exists and is _writable_." `ksh(1)` makes a subtle hint toward shenanigans: "-w file // True, if file exists and is _writable by current process_." `zsh(1)` defers to `test(1)`, `zshmisc(1)` is worded as `ksh(1)`, and `zshexpn(1)` details some interesting permissions-based globbing. `csh(1)` is hilariously brief: "Write access".

Comment: btw: I accepted Patrick's answer, 1. because you didn't adequately answer the lead-on question: _how can I get a false return code when testing a file that doesn't have the write bit set?_ and 2. because of the snarky lead-in presuming I misunderstood the manpages.

Comment: @Rich The way I read this, I think your comments are coming across as a bit snarky as well. I'm not saying that anything you wrote was wrong, just that it would probably go over better if expressed in a more polite way.

Comment: "I think you have have misunderstood..." is not snarky. Your response however, 100% snarky.

Comment: @Rich Also, while the manpages might not have been crystal clear, Stephen has stated that you may have "misunderstood *what -w does*", and not what _manpages_ say, where the former looks to be the case, hence the question

Answer (score 2):

The root user can do as she pleases, "normal" file permissions are no limitation. It won't directly execute a plain file without any eXecute permissions, just for a bit of insurance against foot target practice.